# Automatic Tab / Insert spaces as tab setting switch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

It happens sometimes to switch between codebases using different strategy for indentantion, in term of using pure tabs or spaces instead of tab. Since each codebase reasonably want to preserve the coding style, the developer has to remember to switch to the proper setting each time he change the project he's working on. Is there some way to do this automatically, or having the setting saved as a property on the project/solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS, out-of-the-box, only supports per-user-per-machine settings, including code formatting.

There are third-party add-ins that enable per-project settings. [This example add-in](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2010/08/loading-per-solution-settings-with-visual-studio-2008.html) provides support for VS2008.

Another option is to perform the formatting externally, one option is "Uncrustify", which is blogged about [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100905214224/http://scientificninja.com/blog/per-project-code-formatting-in-visual-studio).